# How to assign colours to specific genes in gggenes arrowplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, hex

I am new to R and I am trying to make an arrowplot. However, the basic gggenes set3 colour theme only has 12 colours and I need more.

I want to assign a group of genes with colour (eg, glycosyltransferases all red and methyltransferases all blue)

I have added an extra column to my df named "colour" and assigned each gene with one hex code (#c1ffc1) - just to test that all genes could change colour before going through and assigning the ones for glycosyltransferases etc - I managed to get it to change colour once and now it isn't working?

Here is the code example with three genes

```
#add colour column to assign to genes
> colour <- c("#c1ffc1")
> df1$colour <- colour
> #change colour
> library(ggplot2)
> library(gggenes)
> ggplot(df1, aes(xmin = start, xmax = end, y = molecule, fill = colour)) +
+   geom_gene_arrow() +
+   geom_gene_label(aes(label = gene)) + 
+   facet_wrap(~ molecule, scales = "free", ncol = 1) + 
+   theme(legend.position="top") + xlim(0,37841) + scale_fill_discrete(name = "gene", labels = c("VanH", "VanA", "VanX"))
```

```
 molecule start   end  strand   gene  orientation  colour
 KJ364518.1  2314  3345 reverse vanH 1  #f15854
 KJ364518.1  3347  4387 reverse vanA 1  #f15854
 KJ364518.1  4384  4992 reverse vanX 1  #f15854
 KJ364518.1  6334  7125 reverse ajrR 1  #faa43a
 KJ364518.1  7246  8097 reverse pdh  1  #5da5da
 KJ364518.1  8410 10272 reverse tri  1  #b276b2
```

Thanks so much in advance,
Lucy

Comment: Without sample data it's rather difficult to know, but ... I'm inferring that `gene` is a categorical variable, and attempting to differentiate more than (say) 7 distinct colors can be problematic even without taking into account color-blindness and other issues. But ... often you can use `aes(color=I(colour))` (or add to an existing `aes(..)`) to force ggplot to use your pre-defined colors within the data.

Comment: @r2evans Hi, thank you so much for responding! I have edited the post to add an image of the df, hopefully this makes more sense?

Comment: Thanks! And for that ... Please do not post (only) an image of code/data/errors: it breaks screen-readers and it cannot be copied or searched (ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please include the code, console output, or data (e.g., `data.frame(...)` or the output from `dput(head(x))`) directly. (I'm not going to spend time transcribing data.)

Comment: @r2evans sincere apologies, I am very new to this... my data is a table is there a way to input that so you can see?

Comment: If you copy-paste the output of `dput(head(df1))` to your question, we can use that to reproduce a part of your data.

Comment: @r2evans Thank you! I have copied and pasted..

Answer (score 0):

Your code appears to work fine, the only thing is that you're providing literal colours to the mapping instead of `fill = your_classification_here`. To show literal colours you can use `scale_fill_identity()`.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(gggenes)

txt <- " molecule start   end  strand   gene  orientation  colour
 KJ364518.1  2314  3345 reverse vanH 1  #f15854
 KJ364518.1  3347  4387 reverse vanA 1  #f15854
 KJ364518.1  4384  4992 reverse vanX 1  #f15854
 KJ364518.1  6334  7125 reverse ajrR 1  #faa43a
 KJ364518.1  7246  8097 reverse pdh  1  #5da5da
 KJ364518.1  8410 10272 reverse tri  1  #b276b2"

df1 <- data.table::fread(text = txt)

ggplot(df1, aes(xmin = start, xmax = end, y = molecule, fill = colour)) +
  geom_gene_arrow() +
  geom_gene_label(aes(label = gene)) +
  facet_wrap(~ molecule, scales = "free", ncol = 1) +
  scale_fill_identity()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-05-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thank you so much! The scale_fill_identity worked great!

Comment: Sorry to ask again, buy do you know if there is a way to turn a single gene arrow to face the other direction?

Comment: Probably swapping `xmin` and `xmax`

Comment: Thanks so much! This changes direction of all of the arrows. Do you know if there is a way to isolate a single gene/arrow like this?

Answer (score 0):

When you create your dataframe one of the columns named orientation contains the info Orientation, expressed as 1 or -1. If you add the command

`forward = orientation`

in your ggplot aesthetics it will apply the orientation of each gene.